# What do the "?" and ":" characters do in a line of code in C++

Tags: c++

I was just wondering what the `"?"` and `":"` characters do. I was working on a problem and encountered the `?`. The solution showed a question mark which I have no idea what it does. Also what does the `:` operator do?

```
return firstNum > secondNum ? vector<int>{secondNum, firstNum}:vector<int>{firstNum, secondNum};
```

Answer (score 5):

It's the [ternary conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator)

```
E1 ? E2 : E3
```

> The first operand of the conditional operator is evaluated and
>   contextually converted to bool. After both the value evaluation and
>   all side effects of the first operand are completed, if the result was
>   true, the second operand is evaluated. If the result was false, the
>   third operand is evaluated.

Comment: It is basically similar to an `if (E1) { E2 } else { E3 }` statement, but more flexible because the result of the evaluation can be used in other statements. In this case, the original code is roughly equivalent to `vector<int> temp; if (firstNum > secondNum) { temp = vector<int>{secondNum, firstNum}; } else { temp = vector<int>{firstNum, secondNum}; } return temp;`